# What is the point of using UnitOfWork along with DDD principles?

Tags: domain-driven-design, unit-of-work

Namely, if aggregate root is the transactional boundary and if each AR has its repository, what would be the point of using `UnitOfWork` and group different repositories operations into a single transaction?

Doesn't that actually stand against the fundamentals of DDD where an AR is a transaction boundary?

I just can't reconcile those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "change one aggregate at a time" is a suggestion to follow closely, but it's not a strict rule that can't *never* be broken. There *may* be situations where it just make sense to break it, depends on what's your domain.

But keep in mind, you don't need an UoW in those scenario either. It's infrastructure, an implementation details. Can use or not use it, it will not have an impact on the DDD design you apply, nor will invalidate it.

Also, UoW aren't useful only for having to manage more than one AR at the same time. You can use them to create repository that behave like in-memory
persistent collections. (i.e, repository that have an `add`, `remove`, `find` methods, but don't need a `save` or `persist`). The UoW can keep track of the changes, and flush the transaction later on.

Comment: wouldn't it invalidate a ddd design if it would rely on transactionality insured by infrastructure as opposed to the one insured by AR design/boundaries? PS. i am writing in the context of 7 out of 10 examples of ddd use unit of work which might make one think it's the way to go and not an exceptional tool to use.